# How to make a tethering or hotspot active in ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, hot-spot

My platform: Google nexus 4.
How to make a tethering or hotspot active in ubuntu-touch for sharing internet connection via phone's 3G?

Comment: I have the same question but I think it isn't possible for the moment. Not sure ^^"

Answer (score 1):

With the latest OTA-update 6 available for all officially supported phones you can find the hotspot option under System Settings/Network now.

Comment: It doesn't work. It always asks for password, even I input. I don't know why.

Comment: Cannnot really help you here, works flawlessly in my Meizu MX4. Maybe you shoud try a restart or a different password... Try more than 8 characters.

Comment: Tried to restart, no changes. But yeah, it's promising. There are someone working on it.

Comment: I have set the hotspot but instead share the 4g connection it share the wifi, if I try to disable wifi, hotspot is also disabled